# Issue with performSegueWithIdentifier several times

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios6

I am developing an application and I would like to disconnect the user if he is no more connected to the server.
I have something like that
The login is created with a navigation Controller
navigation Controller
|
|
login --> ShowSomeInterface --> webview
   ^**___________________________**|
   |**_____________________________**^
The view are changed with the push style.
Login.m :

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

CGSize kbSize;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];  

    // manage the display of the keyboard.
    // it will be useful when the user will click on a field to manage the layout (It will move it) to have the better view possible
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:@"UIKeyboardDidHideNotification" object:nil];

}

- (BOOL) signin {
    if (![NetworkAvailable isNetworkAvailable]) {
        [self alertMessage:@"internet": @"NoConnection" :@"OK"];
        return NO;
    }
    if(  something   ) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hasBeenDisconnected" sender:self];
    else [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Login.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChoiceViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

webview.m

```
@interface WebViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation WebViewController

bool timeIsUp_Reconnection=NO;
NSTimer *timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_webView setDelegate:self];

    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: ... ]];

    [self launchTimer];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [super viewWillAppear:FALSE];
}

-(void) disconnectUser
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"disconnectUser" sender:self];
}

@end
```

webview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

When the application detect that the user has been disconnected from the server, the application will launch the login interface to ask him to relog him. After that, the application will directly launch the webview and will not launch the other interface(ShowSomeInterface).
This will work for the first time. The user will be correctly disconnected but when the server disconnect an other time the user, the application will not launch the login interface a second time.
This is the code I added to change the View

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"disconnect" sender:self];
```

Is it the wrong way to change the view on iOS ?

Comment: Do you have a segue with the identifier disconnect in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes sure. They have an identifier. This is weird because it works for the first disconnection but not for a second one

Comment: What do the …. represent in your diagram? And to confirm: are you saying the disconnect seque should launch the web view?

Comment: it represent something else. When I connect the user I add other interfaces. This is only for the first connection.

Comment: Than you haven't shown enough information. Your question isn't exactly clear what the GUI flow is and where the problem is. For example in your diagram what arrow corresponds to the disconnect seque. When you say you go back to the login interface, go back to it from where, how?

Comment: What type is the segue? Are you ever popping / dismissing controllers?

Comment: I changed my description. The style of the segue is PUSH. I never dismiss or pop them.

Comment: Still not enough information, you need to show much more code where the login view is being created and where/how its displayed. Also your  comment about never dismissing or popping them could be very important. Much more info needed (and are you saying web view is Safari and not a UIWebView? It sounds like you are saying that but you need to be clear).

Comment: Is it enough information ? I tried to add important part of my code. It is a UIWebView

Comment: You never go back to a previous view controller with a segue, unless you are using an unwind segue. If you do, you're not really going back, you're creating a new instance of the controller you're going to.

Comment: okay. So I guess I want to create a new instance. I'm really not used to iOS. It is easier I think with android and the intent to change the view. Is it possible to do the same thing in iOS : open a new instance ? I really don't understand the storyboard.